# How to check if a character in a string is contained within parenthesis in JAVA?

Tags: java, string, pattern-matching, brackets

I have a requirement where I have to replace multiple occurences of a character (say @) from a string which are NOT contained within parenthesis. It is guaranteed that the input string will have valid balanced parenthesis. There can be multiple pairs of parenthesis in the whole string.

Example:
*String str = "How @ are (you @ doing) today @.";*

Expected output after replacing '@' symbols(which are outside parenthesis) by #:

*How # are (you @ doing) today #.*

I can take out the string within parenthesis, do replacement and put parenthesis text back. But I am looking for an easier and cleaner approach.

Comment: Can you include your attempt at solving this?

Comment: One line using RegEx: `String str = "How @ are (you @ doing) today @.".replaceAll("@(?=[^\\)]*?(?:\\(|$))", "#");`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not mention if nesting is possible and possible size of String data. here is a possible easy to understand code.

if stack is empty => we are outside brackets => replaceON else OFF

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "How @ are (you @ do(ok@ok)ing) today @.";

        char candidate = '@';
        char replacement = '#';
        boolean replaceFlag = true;

        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();

        StringBuilder newData = new StringBuilder();

        for(char c: data.toCharArray()) {
            if (c == '(') {
                stack.push(c);
                replaceFlag = false;
            } else if(c == ')') {
                stack.pop();
            }

            if (stack.empty()) {
                replaceFlag = true; // we are not inside parenthesis
            }

            if (c == candidate && replaceFlag) c = replacement;

            newData.append(c);
        }

        System.out.println("Old data: "+ data);
        System.out.println("New data: "+ newData);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah this is exactly what you need..

```
/**
 *@author jore
 *@version 1.0 2/1/2021
 */
public class replacer
{
  public static void main(String... a)
  {
    /* All these yield correct outpUt */
    String input = "How @ are (you @ doing) today @.";
//    String input = How @ are @ ... @ ... (you @ doing (...@...)..@ ) gghhh @ today @ ( hhh @ uuu (.. @.. ) huu ( hyyy @ bhh @ ) hhh @ ) hhh @..@";
    
    int opened_brackets = 0; //To keep track of opened brackets preventing ..(@..(@..)..#).. and allow complex nesting
    char[] temp_array = input.toCharArray(); //To ease random access in input
    char c; // temp char for testing
    
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
      c = temp_array[i];
      if (c == '(') opened_brackets++; //record opened brackets (reason as explained above
      else if (c == ')') opened_brackets--; //record closure of bracket too...
      if (opened_brackets == 0 && c == '@') temp_array[i] = '#'; // Now replacing is fine if opened brackets are == 0, ot means the character is not in brackets
    }
    
    String output = new String(temp_array); //re-create edited output
    System.out.println(output); //....u know what this does.....¿?
  }
}
```

Output 1 : `How # are (you @ doing) today #.`

Output 2 : `# -- replacer How # are # ... # ... (you @ doing (...@...)..@ ) gghhh # today hhh @ uuu (.. @.. ) huu ( hyyy @ bhh @ ) hhh @ ) hhh #..#`

I have created a `temp_array` to allow quick random access..now i keep track of opened brackets to prevent replacement of `@` in nested brackets...other than just waiting for `)` to replace..if `0` brackets are opened.. it means that `@` is misplaced (out of brackets and should be replacedbinstantly...hope it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be keeping a 'for loop' to read all the characters of the string,
Example:

```
String str = "How @ are (you @ doing) today @.";
        char ab ='';
       for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
        {
         ab = str.charAt(i);
         if(ab!='(')
           // check if character is '@' and replace
         else{
           //print as it is; 
            while(ab != ')')
            {//print ab as it is & increment the value of i
            }
           }
           
         }
```